# How to create a Timeline view with draggable components in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, containers, timeline

I would like to create a timeline in swift, like a timeline in classical music software.

What's the container (Collection Views, TableView, Scroll view etc..) looks like to best to design this?

[image]

Comment: find anything ?

Answer (score 0):

NSCollectionView gives you the greatest flexibility for designing this, with the background cells rendered as supplementary views.